# Regular Expression for C#

Tags: c#, regex

when we would submit things like quotation marks, or ellipses, or bullet points, they would show up as a big square on the web page or they would be escaped out and be a string of control characters, like $&&$. so, we want to find or check for those squares, control sequences, and other strange Unicode character types.

so we need regular expression that check all these.Can you please give me the regular expression for this.

Actually this would happen when we enter quotation marks, or ellipses, or bullet points in any user control. Since these are non standard ASCII characters. so  i need to check for them .

i need a regular expression that check a string for any non-standard ASCIi characters.

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to be using a Regular Expression to do this.

You need to HTML Encode the characters so they show up properly in HTML.

Comment: I'm not sure HTML encoding is the problem here. The first part looks like a font problem. I have no idea about the second part.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to work around the problem by replacing some problematic characters, I think it would be better to actually fix the problem.

If some characters show up as squares, that probably means you are using some font that doesn't support them. You should try using another font.

I have never seen “a string of control characters” like `$&&$`. You should figure out what part of your code generates it and stop it from doing that.